# Nvidia Driver won't load/stay loaded after update to 14.04.5

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I just did a dist-upgrade of 14.04 to 14.04.5

After a reboot, my second monitor stopped being detected. So I purged and reinstalled the nvidia drivers (340).

After a reboot again, still no second monitor.

```
/var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

Shows:

```
[    30.969] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    30.980] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    30.980] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    30.980] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    30.980] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
```

So, I checked:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
```

And got:

```
Selection    Path                                  Priority   Status
-----------------------------------------------------------
0        /usr/lib/nvidia-340/ld.so.conf            8604      auto mode
1        /usr/lib/nvidia-340-prime/ld.so.conf      8603    manual mode
2        /usr/lib/nvidia-340/ld.so.conf            8604    manual mode
* 3      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf   500   manual mode
```

This looks like the problem. So I chose '0' and rebooted. Still only one monitor. Rechecked

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
```

Which gives me the same output. So the change isn't sticking.

I selected '0' again, and then logged out of using the control within the X session. This immediately brings my second monitor to life. But, I can't log in. I enter my password and the screen flickers and I am continually prompted for my password.

I also tried:

```
sudo ldconfig    
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

But when I reboot I still have only one working monitor and the same mesa selection.

Any advice on how I can get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this fixed with commands from [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1363675)

```
sudo update-alternatives --auto x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
sudo ldconfig
sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
sudo chmod -x /usr/bin/gpu-manager
```

Now nvidia is being loaded, both monitors work, and I can log in.

Comment: The best way to avoid these problems is to install drivers from Ubuntu repos, or the `graphics-drivers` PPA.

Comment: That's where I installed then from, so these errors were unexpected.